# @PostConstruct never called when using in EJB Singleton Bean using SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor

Tags: jboss, singleton, ejb-3.1

I'm trying to make use of an EJB 3.1 Singleton with a `SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor`. I also need to use a post-construct method, but unfortunately the method is never called.

I'm using JBOSS EAP 6.4.

```
@Startup
@Singleton
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
public class Continuum implements IContinuum {

    @Resource
    TimerService timerService;

    @Autowired
    private HvMeldungenServiceIfc hvService;

    @Autowired
    private ContinuumConfig config;

    @Override
    public HvMeldungenServiceIfc getHvService() {
        return hvService;
    }

    @Override
    public ContinuumConfig getConfig() {
        return config;
    }

    @Override
    @PostConstruct
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Continuum start() Method invoked!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to narrow your problem down? For instance, add a default constructor an check if it's ever called? Do your JBoss logs have any useful info?

Comment: I'm having the same issue on WAS. The constructor ís called and it ís being bound to `java:global/` and `ejblocal:` but postconstruct and the timers are never called. If i remove the interceptor the timer works, but I don't have the spring beans.